# Web Embeddable Screenshare Software

Tags: video, video-streaming, google-hangouts, screensharing

I want to embed screensharing into my web app.

The idea would be that one user would broadcast their screen via a screensharing software (ideally this would also be via the web) and others could subscribe to this channel.

Screen Hero requires that everyone download their software, which is not ideal.  Google Hangouts API is too restrictive for my purposes.  I want this all to happen inside an iframe or flash/HTML5 element in my website and I don't believe that that is feasible.  I'd also prefer it if my users did n't have to connect with the G+ accounts.

Are there any known, cheap (or free) options?  Any non-cheap options?

Am I misinformed about the Google Hangouts (or Plus) API, such that I can easily embed?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I researched the same lately and the only two services I could find after a while of researching were

http://www.screenleap.com

or (not free, but more powerful)

http://www.mikago.com